# Jmeter : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Dimensions (width=27118 height=6346092) are too large. at dummy sampler

Tags: java, jmeter

I have dummy sampler where added json response of size 220 kb ,

seeing this error whenever clicking on this dummy sampler

current Xss =1.5G ,Xmx=2.5G

```
2021-10-25 16:04:02,779 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Dimensions (width=27118 height=6346092) are too large
    at java.awt.image.SampleModel.<init>(SampleModel.java:130) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.image.SinglePixelPackedSampleModel.<init>(SinglePixelPackedSampleModel.java:144) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.image.Raster.createPackedRaster(Raster.java:798) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.image.Raster.createPackedRaster(Raster.java:475) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.image.DirectColorModel.createCompatibleWritableRaster(DirectColorModel.java:1032) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.<init>(BufferedImage.java:351) ~[?:?]
    at com.apple.laf.AquaPainter$AquaSingleImagePainter.createImage(AquaPainter.java:193) ~[?:?]
    at com.apple.laf.AquaPainter$AquaSingleImagePainter.lambda$paintFromSingleCachedImage$0(AquaPainter.java:178) ~[?:?]
    at sun.awt.image.MultiResolutionCachedImage.getResolutionVariant(MultiResolutionCachedImage.java:84) ~[?:?]
    at sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.getResolutionVariant(SunGraphics2D.java:3310) ~[?:?]
    at sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.drawHiDPIImage(SunGraphics2D.java:3138) ~[?:?]
    at sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.drawImage(SunGraphics2D.java:3376) ~[?:?]
    at sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.drawImage(SunGraphics2D.java:3326) ~[?:?]
    at
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that your window dimensions (height and width) are [somehow too large](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/739769c8fc4b496f08a92225a12d07414537b6c0/src/java.desktop/share/classes/java/awt/image/SampleModel.java#L126)

```
public SampleModel(int dataType, int w, int h, int numBands)
{
    long size = (long)w * h;
    if (w <= 0 || h <= 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Width ("+w+") and height ("+
                                           h+") must be > 0");
    }
    if (size >= Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Dimensions (width="+w+
                                           " height="+h+") are too large");
    }
```

you have `27118` * `6346092` which gives `172093322856` which is a little bit larger than [32-bit integer maximum value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2,147,483,647)

The question why JMeter tries to display that large window is something I cannot answer without seeing full [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) preferably with [debug logging enabled](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging/), it may be somehow connected with LAF/MacOS, you could try something like choosing another LAF from "Options -> Look and Feel" menu:

[image]

or if you cannot access it as well you can use `[-J` command-line argument][6](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override) like:

```
jmeter -Jjmeter.laf=CrossPlatform -t /path/to/your/test.jmx
```